# IndexError: list index out of range PYTHON (w/o using for loop)

Tags: python

I am trying to find averages from a text file. The text file has columns of numbers and I want to find the average of each column. I get the follwoing error:
IndexError: list index out of range

The code I am using is:

```
import os

os.chdir(r"path of my file")
file_open = open("name of my file", "r")
file_write = open ("average.txt", "w")

line = file_open.readlines()
list_of_lines = []
length = len(list_of_lines[0])
total = 0


for i in line:
    values = i.split('\t')
    list_of_lines.append(values)

count = 0
for j in list_of_lines:
    count +=1

for k in range(0,count):
    print k
    list_of_lines[k].remove('\n')



for o in range(0,count):
    for p in range(0,length):
        print list_of_lines[p][o]
        number = int(list_of_lines[p][o])    
        total + number
    average = total/count
    print average
```

The error is in line

```
length = len(list_of_lines[0])
```

Please let me know if I can provide anymore information.

Comment: What do you expect `len(list_of_lines[0])` and more specifically `list_of_lines[0]` to be directly after `list_of_lines = []`?

Comment: `list_of_lines = []` and `length = len(list_of_lines[0])` don't look good.

Comment: `list_of_lines = []
length = len(list_of_lines[0])` what do you expect that to do? what value should `length` take?

Comment: `length = len(list_of_lines)` (after fixing the index error using existing answers) is evaluated once as you run top-to-bottom through the script. Every time you want an up-to-date length you need to call `len()` again. `length` will always be zero in this script so your last `for` loop will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to get the length of something in the array, not the array itself.

Try this:

`length = len(list_of_lines)`

Comment: @new_coder Np, please don't forget to upvote and select the best answer

Comment: @MoH. upvoting takes at least 10 reputation and asking an OP to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is better done with a link to how it works. (especially for new users)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen good point, also I didn't notice that OP was under 10 rep.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `length = len(list_of_lines[0])`

`line_of_lines` is defined right above this line, as a list with 0 items in it. As a result, you cannot select the first item (index number 0) because index number 0 does not exist. Therefore, it is out of range.